# Problem loading static content to Web App using Django

Tags: python, django, web

I have difficulty displaying static content in my web, I can't figure out where's the issue

Here's my browser:

[image]

this is my `settings.py` file:

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
    STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'first_app',
    ]

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_DIR,
    ]
```

`views.py` file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    # Create your views here.

    def index (request):
        my_dict={'insert_me':"Hello I am from views.py!"}
        return render(request,'first_app/index.html', context=my_dict)
```

`url.py` file:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from first_app import views
    urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
    ]
```

and my templates file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Django Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hi this is a picture from Zakopane</h1>
        <img src= "{% static "images/picture1.jpg" %}" alt="Picture not found">

      </body>
    </html>
```

I get an error saying "GET /static/images/picture1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1683" on the terminal.

Would appreciate any help
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this lines to your settings file:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

for debug mode add this path in your urls.py file:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and make sure you collectstatic before the test!

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Hi Sarkan, I don't have any folder called "staticfiles" I'm not sure what you're meaning with it

Comment: when you collectstatic this folder will be created and your static files copied to it and read from it.